# Fatal error when unwrapping a segued string (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, string, int, swift3

This is my code I don't know what I did wrong. All of the problems are in function steve. LebelText is a timer timer label that is segued from another view controller. So i want to take lebetText convert it to a int to subtract 1 from it then reconvert it back to a string to display the number.

This is view Controller a. The texted being segued is lebelText.

```
 import UIKit

class testViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var lazel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var plax: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var stopx: UIButton!

var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0.0
var isRunning = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()





}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController : restultViewController = segue.destination as! restultViewController

    DestViewController.LebelText = lazel.text!

}
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

   if !isRunning{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(testViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }
    plax.isEnabled = false
    stopx.isEnabled = true

        }

 @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {

    plax.isEnabled = true
    stopx.isEnabled = false
    timer.invalidate()
    isRunning = false


   }


   func update(){
    counter += 0.1
    lazel.text = String(format: "1%f", counter)
    lazel.text = "\(counter)"


    }}
```

this is view controller b. The goal is to go to take lebelText convert it to a int to subtracted 1 from it. Then convert it back to a string so it can be displayed.

```
   import UIKit
   class restultViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var dxe: UILabel!


    var LebelText = String()

    let myInt = Int()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  steve()

   }
  func steve(){

var eq = LebelText

var intValue = Int(eq)

let vx = intValue! - 1
let ramit = String(vx)
dxe.text = ramit
  }
```

Comment: a Little more detail would be good, also your variable naming doesn't help to much to understand what you want to achieve, maybe you could explain that a little more as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here at all. First, you instantiate  a string called LebelText, with no value, then you assign it to another variable, eq, which then, you try to cast into an Int. What.. what's going on?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios. LebelText is a label that is segued from another view controller. lebelText is a label that displays a number where the timer was stoped. Then I am trying to subtract 1 from lebelText. So i am trying to take lebelText from string to int (where I will subtract 1 from the int) then convert the int to a string So I can display on label dxe.

Comment: LebelText is not a UILabel object. and where did you calling the timer object ? r u passing the LebelText value to restultViewController?

Comment: @Sahil lebelText is being segued from another label on another view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so to get rid of the optional and to be sure it all works you should do like

```
if let intValue = Int(eq) {
     vx = intValue - 1
     dxe.text = String(vx)
} else {
     //do some stuff if you  cannot convert eq to Int
}
```

but I would recommend you to start with some easier tasks, it looks like you did not completely learn basics.

```
import UIKit
class restultViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!
    public var myText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.parseData()
    }

    private func parseData(){
        guard let unwrapedText = self.myText else {
            //you didn't pass string
            return
        }
        if let myInt = Int(unwrapedText) {
            myInt = myInt - 1 
            self.someLabel.text = String(myInt)
        } else {
            //you string is not convertable to int
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this did not work because the variables are not defined.

Comment: I've edit the code how it actually should look like, you need to reset outlet if you change its name

Comment: this takes away the error but does not carry the value over. There is no value display. It does not display the value.

Comment: try to change `Int(unwrapedText)` in my code for `Double(unwrapedText)`. Int is `1`, and it is look like you have `1.1` which is Double

Answer (score -1):

You Can just do this.

```
import UIKit
   class restultViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var dxe: UILabel!


    var LebelText = String()

    let myInt = Int()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  steve()

   }
  func steve(){

var eq = Int(LebelText.text)

eq = eq - 1

dxe.text = String(eq)
  }
```

Comment: error message coming up on var eq = Int(LebelText.text) saying that string has no member text.

Comment: We need more info of your code, since you are using LebelText as a String and Not as a Label, that`s why it doesn't have a member .text. Maybe you can try removing just the .text But Since Im not sure how you send the other label as a segue can`t know.

Comment: Added both view controllers.